# Socket.io chat reload page when message is sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, socket.io

I'm having a go with the socket.io tutorial at http://socket.io/get-started/chat/, but my problem is that when i send a message the page reloads instead of persisting.

The only difference is that i used pure DOM instead of using jquery as in tutorial. This is the original code:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
```

And this is mine:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      document.querySelector('form')
      .addEventListener('submit', function () {
        socket.emit('chat message',
        document.querySelector('#m').value);
        document.querySelector('#m').value = '';
        return false;
      });

      socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        document.querySelector('#messages').appendChild(li);
        li.innerText = msg;
      });
    </script>
```

If i replace mine with the jquery one, it works as a charm.
Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: So it's the jQuery version that doesn't work ?

Comment: Nope, jquery is working, javascript isn't

Comment: *"If i replace the jquery one with mine, it works as a charm"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `preventDefault`, `return false` doesn't work for `addEventListener`

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    socket.emit('chat message', document.querySelector('#m').value);
    document.querySelector('#m').value = '';
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works. it looks like jquery calls preventdefault on its own.

Comment: Yes, using return false in jQuery calls preventDefault and stopPropagation

Comment: Finally, This solution worked for me. I have wasted more than 3 hours fixing it. Thanks a lot. @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to throw this out here because I landed at this page when having a similar issue where I WAS using jquery and it was reloading.

The problem was that I had the Jquery stuff in the head tags, and not in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Move the event emit script below the `form` tag.

```
<form>
  <input id="m" />
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
      return false;
  });
  // more code..
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using

```
<form>
 <input id="m" />
 <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

and you are submitting it using jQuery. Submitting a form will make the page get a refresh.

Instead of using

You can go with:

```
<div id="sendbottom">
    <input type="text" id="msg">
    <input type="button" id="send" value="send">
</div>
```

And for sending message use JQuery as follows:

```
$('#send').on('click',function () {
    var msg2send = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    document.getElementById('msg').value = '';
    var iHTML = document.getElementById('messaging').innerHTML;
    var newiHTML = iHTML + '<br> <b>You</b> : '+ msg2send;
    document.getElementById('messaging').innerHTML = newiHTML;
    //Your Code Here
});
```